# Count rows from another SQL table in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables from which with only one query I have to get the result
I have the url table and the vote table.

```
Table url

|id           |url            |category|
|.............|...............|........|
|1            |example1.com   |1       |
|2            |example2.com   |1       |
|3            |example3.com   |2       |
|4            |example4.com   |1       |

Table vote

|id           |note        |
|.............|............|
|1            |1           |
|1            |2           |
|1            |1           |
|2            |1           |
```

I wanted to do a query that shows me all the fields of the url table and the count of all the rows with note 1.

I have tried with this query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.url, u.cat, COUNT(*) as countnote 
FROM vote v, url u 
WHERE u.cat=1 and v.note=1
```

but it only shows me one row.

Expected result:

```
|id           |url            |countnote|Category|
|.............|...............|.........|........|
|1            |example1.com   |2        |1       |
|2            |example2.com   |1        |1       |
|4            |example4.com   |0        |1       |
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: SELECT u.id, u.url, u.cat, COUNT(*) as countnote FROM vote v, url u WHERE u.cat=1 and v.note=1 GROUP BY u.id, u.url, u.cat

Comment: It does not show the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just suggest a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT u.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM vote v
        WHERE v.id = u.id AND v.note = 1
       ) as num_note_1
FROM url
WHERE u.cat = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH URLL (ID,URLL,CATEGORY)AS
 (
    SELECT 1,'EXAMPLE1.COM',1
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'EXAMPLE2.COM',1
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'EXAMPLE3.COM',2
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'EXAMPLE4.COM',1
),
VOTE(ID,NOTE)AS
(
    SELECT 1,1 
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,2
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,1
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,1       
)
--the query
SELECT UR.ID,UR.URLL,UR.CATEGORY,COALESCE(XQ.CNTT,0)CNTT
FROM URLL AS UR
LEFT JOIN 
 (
   SELECT COUNT(ID)CNTT,V.ID
    FROM VOTE AS V
     WHERE V.NOTE=1
     GROUP BY V.ID
 )XQ ON UR.ID=XQ.ID
WHERE UR.CATEGORY=1
```